# Scala TrieMap.computeHash fails unexpectedly on Spark Cluster, but HashMap works with same code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing, broadcast

I am trying to refactor some existing code to run fully in cluster-mode and have been running into an unexpecteded NullPointerException under Scala 2.12.10 when trying to use the TrieMap, see

[TrieMap.scala (Official Scala Lang)](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.10/src/library/scala/collection/concurrent/TrieMap.scala)

The error only appears when running Spark in **Cluster mode**. "Local" mode runs fine.

Using *HashMap* instead of TrieMap works in **both** modes without problems. A Previous dev switched to TrieMap from HashMap and it is desired that I use it.

Any attempt to use the update() or put() functions of TrieMap fails when the computeHash() function (line 823 of the linked official Scala source code) is called, allegedly due to a NullPointer.

```
def computeHash(k: K) = hashingobj.hash(k)
```

However, I was not able to find out what the problem is. The only input to computeHash() is the key, which I was able to verify in the SparkUI that the value exists on workers. In our case, the key here is a Case Class containing only a string.
Furthermore, the hashingObj.hash() used by computeHash() should be set with default settings defined by the parameterless constructor of TrieMap. Thus it itself should also not be null.

I was thinking that this may be an issue with a missing broadcast value, but all needed values show as being non-null when checking via SparkUI.

I found some code examples, but they do not seem to use their inputs any differently than we do.
[TrieMap Examples](https://www.programcreek.com/scala/scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap)

Thanks for any help and best regards.

- Verified that key and TrieMap instance are not null
- Checke if if all Broadcast variables are not null
- Checked that key.## calculates a value
- Analyzed underlying source code regarding default hashing function => [Default Hashing function: byteswap32](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.10/src/library/scala/util/hashing/package.scala)

**Edit1: Stack Trace**
The top of the Stack Trace looks like this

```
23/11/02 11:02:36 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 62.0 (TID 126, 172.27.112.108, executor 0): java.lang.NullPointerException
at scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap.computeHash(TrieMap.scala:823)
at <ourPath>.lib.cache.Cache.initialize(Cache.scala:64)
at ...
```

Cache is a custom class we use, but the initialize() function only has the aforementioned key as parameter and crashed when TrieMap tries to compute a hash (e.g. in this case when calling TrieMap.put)

**Edit2: Pseudo Code and "Chain of Error"**

Drilling down from "top level" of error source to final one reported in Strack Trace. Last line always is the one where error is tracked in Stack Trace.

1. Within our job:

```
    <someEvent>Partition.toList
      .groupBy(<ourEvent> => <ourEvent>.someId)
       .flatMap(event => {
           val openLots = <ourEventHandler>.getOpenLots(event._1, <lotBroadcast>) 
// this is the "top-level" of our code that is involved in the error stack trace
```

2. Within .getOpenLots:

```
    val lotsForXY = <cacheBroadcast>.getValue.getValues(SomeCaseClass(idString), None)
```

3. Within our Cache.getValues(key: K, filteringKey: Option())

```
    var valuesList = getCachedValuesForKey(key)
```

4. Cache.getCachedValuesForKey(key: K)

```
    if(!this.<theTrieMap>.contains(key))
        initialize(key)
```

5. Cache.initialize(key: K)

```
    this.<theTrieMap>.put(key, <someListBuffer[V]>)
```

Note: The TrieMap is created when the Cache itself is created:

```
    private val <theTrieMap>: TrieMap[K, ListBuffer[V]] = new TrieMap[K, ListBuffer[V]]
```

6. TrieMap.put(key: K, value: V)

```
         val hc = computeHash(key) // NullPointerException here
```

7. TrieMap.computeHash(key: K)

```
def computeHash(k: K) = hashingobj.hash(k)
```

The computeHash(key) fails due to a **NullPointerException**

- I know that key is not null here, because the worker logs can show me its values
- the only remaining explanation I can come up with is that the hashingObj used internally in the TrieMap is not properly set, but
  then that must be a bug, since we use the default    parameterless
  constructor given in the [official Scala class](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.10/src/library/scala/collection/concurrent/TrieMap.scala)
- I also tried a simpler TrieMap[Int, String], which also crashes when trying to compute the hash. So it is unlikely to be caused by
  our key

Comment: can you provide the stack trace for the npe?  it seems unlikely hashingobj is null after serialisation but you could verify that by checking if map.hashing() is null.
That said broadcast variables are meant to be immutable - why are you updating or put'ing anything on it?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your input, added top of Stack. Regarding the broadcasts, they are not changed. The TrieMap is local to each workers and only changed there at that point. But I had suspected that some necessary input may not reach them via the broadcasts. Have not anything to substantiate that, though.
I'll check reg. hashing.

Comment: sorry, that's not clear to me, if they are on workers only, where does the broadcast come in? can you possibly pseudo code it?

Comment: @Chris Added some pseudo-code to make it clearer.

Comment: ok, it still looks like you are broadcasting an object you then manipulate on the executors, which has undefined behaviour.   I'd assume you are witnessing jmm issues, try to mark the map as @volatile or, more usefully, keep it completely outside of the broadcast object

Comment: @Chris ok, I can try some refactoring. But, in that case, shouldn't HashMap also have had the same error?

Comment: If it's jmm, you may have just been lucky, similarly you could try a lazy on it